# Recursive sum function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Essentially I am trying to create a function, r_sum(n), that will return the sum of the first "n" reciprocals: e.g. sum(5) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 .I am new to recursion and am having trouble with the implementation. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def r_sum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1/n
```

I think I have created the base of the function, but I'm not sure where I would have the function call itself. As of now, I realize the function will only return the value of 1/n. How can I add to this so that I have the function call itself to calculate this sum?

Comment: `def sum_to(n): return 0 if n == 0 else 1./n + sum_to(n-1)` — »All too easy.  Maybe you're not as strong as I thought.«

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163040/python-3-recursion-maximum-depth-exceeded Is this part of a course?

Comment: Well, a comment should remain which states that *in Python 3* things like `1/n` will create a float even if `n` is an integer.  Since that is a uncommon thing for other programming languages (even Python 2 will return an int, 0 for most `n`), that comment still makes sense.

Comment: Where are you learning recursion from? Surely it should have examples that show how a function calls itself.

Comment: I realize this was a simple fix, and apologize if the question was redundant. Also, this was not a part of a course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of:

```
sum(5) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5
```

as:

```
sum(5) = 1/5 + sum(4)
sum(4) = 1/4 + sum(3)
sum(3) = 1/3 + sum(2)
sum(2) = 1/2 + sum(1)
sum(1) = 1
```

As such:

```
sum(x) = 1/x + sum(x-1)
sum(1) = 1
```

And thus the last case should be:

```
return 1/n + sum_to(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to think of solving a piece of the problem so that the rest of it is another instance of the same problem, just for a smaller chunk.

```
def sum_to(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0.0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 1.0/n + sum_to(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are better known as [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). It's worth noting that H<sub>0</sub> isn't usually defined, but that's beside the point.

What do you want `sum_to(n)` return? You probably expect `1/n + 1/(n-1) + ...` right? So we shouldn't be simply returning `1/n`. You should look at the rest of that expression and find where you can find `sum_to(n - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a recursive function, you need two things:

- a stop case
- the other general case (which is recursively defined)

Here, your stop case is 0. We know `sum_to(0) == 0`.
The general case is: `sum_to(n) == 1.0/n + sum_to(n - 1)`.

All that is left to do is join these in a function:

```
def sum_to(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    return 1.0/n + sum_to(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using generators is the Pythonic (as opposed to the pedantic) way to solve this problem.

```
def g_sum(n):
    """
    Solution using generators instead of recursion.
    Input validation suppressed for clarity.
    """
    return sum(1/x for x in range(1, n+1))

def r_sum(n):
    """
    Recursive solution proposed by @Alfe
    """
    return 0 if n == 0 else 1/n + r_sum(n-1)
```

Timing the function shows that the generator solution is approx. twice as fast:

- Generator:

  - `%timeit -n 10000 v1 = g_sum(100)`
  - `10000 loops, best of 3: 9.94 µs per loop`
- Recursion:

  - `%timeit -n 10000 v2 = r_sum(100)`
  - `10000 loops, best of 3: 22 µs per loop`

In addition, the recursive implementation will hit a recursion limit very quickly making it very impractical for real-world use.

Specifically: `r_sum(1000)` fails with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways

```
def r_sum(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return (1/n) + r_sum(n-1)
```

or

```
def r_sum(n):
    return sum(map(lambda x:1.0/x, xrange(1, n+1)))
```